# How to compute (X,Y,Z) of a point from given attributes

Tags: python, intersection

[image: Sat/Antenna relation]

Is there a way to compute the geodetic coordinates (Earth Centered) of a satellite S(x,y,z). The original problem is to compute the footprint of an antenna,
given the following information:

```
Antenna(x,y,z) geodetic coordinates (Earth Centered) for an antenna
e = antenna elevation [0:90]
Az = (antenna azimuth) [0:360]
R = Radius of Earth (appr. 6378.1363 km)
h = height of S (in kilometers)
```

If it turns the solution easier, the coordinates of A and S can be written in (lat,long,h) format:

```
Antenna(lat,long, h = 0)
S(lat,,long,h)
```

I'm trying to write the code in python, so I can use some libs (like pylint and pyproj, for instance)

Comment: It should be a simple surveying problem called "trigonometric heighting". Is e observed in atmosphere? Apply a "curvature and refraction correction". I can help further, after you clarify...

Comment: You've drawn it as though the distances are huge. What sort of accuracies are involved (cm, m)? Are your XYZ coords on local mapping plane, or Earth centered? What are the approx distances of A from base of antenna? And h? Please [edit] the new info into the question.

Comment: And welcome to GIS SE  :-)

Comment: I'm trying to compute the antenna's footprint, given its earth centered coordinates (X,Y,Z), its azimuth and elevation, for a satellite with height h. The antenna would receive (in my simulation) earth resource satellites, so the distances can be given in kilometers.

Comment: So I can understand your terminlogy, when you write "antenna footprint", do you mean the ground station's antenna?  And if so, are you defining its footprint to be the area enclosed by the circle on the sphere whose points are the nadir intersections on the sphere for satellites viewable at a particular ground station antenna elevation?  Or maybe it's something completely different?

Comment: It is exactly what I need, the circle on the Earth's surface that describes this intersections.